# PHP dropzone issue with post max size

Tags: php, dropzone.js

I am working on a PHP application deployed on a cent os machine having suhosin installed in it. I used dropzone.js with my application and tried to upload a file size more than 20 MB. I configured the ini setting as follows

```
post_max_size = 200M
max_input_time=600
max_execution_time=300
max_file_uploads=20
upload_max_filesize = 200M
upload_tmp_dir = /custom_dir/tmp
```

The tmp is writable, apache has been restarted, display_errors is On, ini_get gives the updated values of php.ini.

Error generated by dropzone is **Server responded with 0 code.**

I tried creating a demo form and uploaded a file size greater than 20 MB it also failed, less than 20MB uploaded working just fine. I thus came to conclusion the error might be fron server side and not from dropzone.

I have reffered [Dropzone.js - maxFilesize increase not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17143884/dropzone-js-maxfilesize-increase-not-working), [Large File Upload Errors with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/757111/large-file-upload-errors-with-php), [1GB file upload using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3836417/1gb-file-upload-using-php), http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-apache-increase-php-upload-limit/ Still am unable to figure out why it's not working. Can any one help ? I know this seems to be duplicate question but trust me I have tried all the specs still getting the issue

Comment: Is suhosin blocking my changes ?

Comment: create empty php file with `phpinfo()` and check this parameters and location of php.ini (Loaded Configuration File)

Comment: @li-on Thanks for quick reply, I tried that it's giving me the same values I configured it with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working suhosin was not the issue It was apache's LimitRequestBody in httpd.conf

> To restricts the total size of the HTTP request body sent from the
>   client use LimitRequestBody Directive. You can add this directive
>   using .htaccess file or httpd.conf file under virtual host or
>   directory configuration options. You can set value (in bytes) from 0
>   (unlimited) to 2147483647 (2GB) that are allowed in a request body.
>
> Example for LimitRequestBody set to 100k bytes (in httpd.conf)
>
> `LimitRequestBody 102400`
>
> [...] Save and close the file. You need to restart or reload the httpd server as follows:
>
> `service httpd restart`
>
> or
>
> `service httpd reload`
>
> **Source:** http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/apache-limiting-upload-size/