# Codeigniter Upload File Sometimes Not Working

Tags: codeigniter-3, image-uploading

I have a website with an upload profile photos for users.

**First Try**

When I try to upload a small size image, the upload was succeed.
This file property :
Size : 500 KB
Width : 900
Height : 900
Type : jpg

**Second Try**

When I try to upload a large iamge, I got error message :
**The uploaded file exceeds the maximum allowed size in your PHP configuration file.**

This file property :
Size : 7,2 MB
Width : 5200
Height : 3500
Type : JPG

This is my config file in my controller :

```
$config['upload_path']   = "./assets/gambar/pengguna/";
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|jpeg|png';
    $config['max_size']      = 25000;
    $config['max_width']     = 7000;
    $config['max_height']    = 7000;
```

I tried to change max_size, max_width, and max_height to 0. But I still get bthe same problem.
Refrence to set it 0 to make it no limit from :
https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html

Comment: set post_max_size and upload_max_filesize  on your server with php setting

Comment: see this links https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3836417/1gb-file-upload-using-php?rq=1

Comment: and this also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12049004/wamp-uploading-large-file

Comment: Thanks for your help