Throwing AH01225: Error reading request entity data while uploading files
We face an issue of failure in upload files of more than a GB in size which will keep printing apache error.logs during upload in progress as:
[Tue May 07 04:16:35.109777 2024] [cgi:error] [pid 30766] (-102)Unknown error -102: [client 10.140.204.23:64774] AH01225: Error reading request entity data, referer: https://10.105.105.84/cgi-bin/pages.cgi?title=cm_net
[Tue May 07 04:17:05.919928 2024] [cgi:error] [pid 30768] (-102)Unknown error -102: [client 10.140.204.23:64802] AH01225: Error reading request entity data, referer: https://10.105.105.84/cgi-bin/pages.cgi?title=cm_net
[Tue May 07 04:17:36.592258 2024] [cgi:error] [pid 30767] (-102)Unknown error -102: [client 10.140.204.23:64849] AH01225: Error reading request entity data, referer: https://10.105.105.84/cgi-bin/pages.cgi?title=cm_net
[Tue May 07 04:18:07.223293 2024] [cgi:error] [pid 30766] (-102)Unknown error -102: [client 10.140.204.23:64884] AH01225: Error reading request entity data, referer: https://10.105.105.84/cgi-bin/pages.cgi?title=cm_net
[Tue May 07 04:18:37.928108 2024] [cgi:error] [pid 30767] (-102)Unknown error -102: [client 10.140.204.23:64916] AH01225: Error reading request entity data, referer: https://10.105.105.84/cgi-bin/pages.cgi?title=cm_net
[Tue May 07 04:19:08.700924 2024] [cgi:error] [pid 30768] (-102)Unknown error -102: [client 10.140.204.23:64950] AH01225: Error reading request entity data, referer: https://10.105.105.84/cgi-bin/pages.cgi?title=cm_net
[Tue May 07 04:19:39.443934 2024] [cgi:error] [pid 30767] (-102)Unknown error -102: [client 10.140.204.23:64980] AH01225: Error reading request entity data, referer: https://10.105.105.84/cgi-bin/pages.cgi?title=cm_net
[Tue May 07 04:20:10.530056 2024] [cgi:error] [pid 30766] (-102)Unknown error -102: [client 10.140.204.23:65029] AH01225: Error reading request entity data, referer: https://10.105.105.84/cgi-bin/pages.cgi?title=cm_net

This is been observed after upgrading httpd-2.4.41 to httpd-2.4.58.
Tried with smaller files which gets uploaded without any issue.
Increased timeout to 600 in httpd.conf and apache2.conf still no luck. Any suggestions?
Edit1:
htaccess looks like below:
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_security.c>
    SecRuleEngine On
    SecRequestBodyAccess On
    SecRequestBodyLimit 2147483648
    SecRequestBodyNoFilesLimit 524288
    SecRequestBodyInMemoryLimit 524288
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_php7.c>
    php_value upload_max_filesize   15000M
    php_value post_max_size                 15001M
    php_value memory_limit  15000M
</IfModule>

and httpd.conf added below line:
LimitRequestBody 3000000000


This question doesn't seem to be programming-related (but server-configuration-related). Please see [help/on-topic] and [tag:apache] for info. Also, check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3836417/1gb-file-upload-using-php

Seems a problem I have faced sometime ago. Try to increase LimitRequestBody in main apache conf or the virtual host conf file:
LimitRequestBody 3000000000
Adapt to your specific needs, this is for ~3GB
See CVE-2022-29404

i have updated the htaccess with below code:

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]


    SecRuleEngine On
    SecRequestBodyAccess On
    SecRequestBodyLimit 2147483648
    SecRequestBodyNoFilesLimit 524288
    SecRequestBodyInMemoryLimit 524288


    php_value upload_max_filesize   15000M
    php_value post_max_size                 15001M
    php_value memory_limit  15000M
 but no luck
Also updated httpd.conf with LimitRequestBody 3000000000 and restarted the apache

For an update, it worked like charm after adding LimitRequestBody 3000000000 and Timeout 600 in /etc/apache2/apache.conf and restarting the apache. Note: File location may change as per your os. Thanks @pierpy for the suggestion.
